# Stacking divs using @media queries

Tags: css, responsive

How do I stack divs using @media with a max width of 768px.

```
<div class="Container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without using flexbox (but the flex way is perfectly fine) you can also use float:

```css
.container::before,.container::after{
  content: " ";
  display:table;
}
.container::after{
  clear:both
}

.box{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  margin-left:2px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .box{
    float:none;
    margin-right:0;
    margin-bottom:2px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand OP correctly, this can be accomplished using flexbox:

```css
.Container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .Container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZxJPOw)